# Why is there a blinking cursor on a \psdots? What is it for?

Tags: pstricks

The red dot is made by `\psdots` while the blue one is made by `\pscircle`. By clicking the red dot viewed by Adobe Acrobat, there will be a blinking cursor. But a blinking cursor does not exist on the blue dot.

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](3,3)
\psdots[linecolor=red](1,1)
\pscircle*[linecolor=blue](2,2){2pt}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Why is there a blinking cursor on a dot produced by `\psdots`? What is it for?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`\psdots` uses characters from a self defined Type-3 *vector font*, also known as a softfont:

```
voss@shania:~/Test> pdffonts test.pdf
name                          type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
----------------------------- ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
Helvetica                     Type 1            Standard         no  no  no       8  0
[none]                        Type 3            Custom           yes no  no      11  0
```

With `\pscircle` you get a graphical object. For a character like the dot the cursor behaves as usual for other characters. And, by the way, it is an example that a Type 3 font can also be a vector font!

Comment: ah +1 more detail than mine, so I deleted mine, David