# Make psdot thicker in width

Tags: pstricks

I am trying to create a number line but the psdot is not bold or thick enough, it should be the same as the arrow's width.

[image: Number line]

Linewidth does not seem to help, this is the full code.

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\psset{xunit=1.0cm,yunit=1.0cm,algebraic=true,dimen=middle,dotstyle=o,dotsize=3pt 0,linewidth=0.8pt,arrowsize=3pt 2,arrowinset=0.25}
\begin{pspicture*}(-4.3,-3.12)(7.3,6.3)
\psline{->}(0.,0.)(6.,0.)
\psline(1.,0.2)(1.,-0.2)
\psline(1.,0.2)(1.,-0.2)
\psline(1.,0.2)(1.,-0.2)
\psline(2.,0.2)(2.,-0.2)
\psline(3.,0.2)(3.,-0.2)
\psline(4.,0.2)(4.,-0.2)
\psline(5.,-0.2)(5.,0.2)
\rput[tl](2.94,-0.3){5}
\rput[tl](1.94,-0.3){4}
\rput[tl](0.94,-0.32){3}
\rput[tl](3.94,-0.3){6}
\rput[tl](4.94,-0.32){7}
\psline{->}(2.98,0.42)(4.98,0.42)
\psdots[linewidth=8pt,dotsize=5pt 0](2.98,0.42)
\end{pspicture*}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think the thickness of `\psdots` can be changed (See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/73087/27635).

You can place a `\pscircle` over it, as a workaround.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\psset{xunit=1.0cm,yunit=1.0cm,algebraic=true,dimen=middle,dotstyle=o,linewidth=0.8pt,arrowsize=3pt 2,arrowinset=0.25}
\begin{pspicture*}(-4.3,-3.12)(7.3,6.3)
\psline{->}(0.,0.)(6.,0.)
\psline(1.,0.2)(1.,-0.2)
\psline(1.,0.2)(1.,-0.2)
\psline(1.,0.2)(1.,-0.2)
\psline(2.,0.2)(2.,-0.2)
\psline(3.,0.2)(3.,-0.2)
\psline(4.,0.2)(4.,-0.2)
\psline(5.,-0.2)(5.,0.2)
\rput[tl](2.94,-0.3){5}
\rput[tl](1.94,-0.3){4}
\rput[tl](0.94,-0.32){3}
\rput[tl](3.94,-0.3){6}
\rput[tl](4.94,-0.32){7}
\psline{->}(2.98,0.42)(4.98,0.42)
\psdots[dotsize=5pt 0](2.98,0.42)
\pscircle(2.98,0.42){2.5pt}
\end{pspicture*}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: `\psdots`  _is_ a graphical object.

Comment: Thanks @Herbert for the tip. Reading your mentioned answer I've thought it wasn't...

Answer (score 5):

There is an optional argument `arrowLW` (arrowLineWidth)

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}

\psset{linewidth=0.8pt,arrowsize=3pt 2,arrowinset=0.25}
\begin{pspicture*}(-1,-1)(8,1)
\psaxes[yAxis=false,Ox=3]{->}(0,0)(-0.9,0)(5,0)
\psline[arrowscale=1.5,arrowLW=2pt]{o->}(2,0.42)(4,0.42)
\end{pspicture*}

\end{document}
```

[image]